# multiple .doc to .docx file conversion using python

Tags: python, .doc

I want to convert all the .doc files from a particular folder to .docx file.

I tried using the following code,

```
import subprocess
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith('.doc'):
        print filename
        subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', filename])
```

But it gives me an error:
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 22):

Here is a solution that worked for me. The other solutions proposed did not work on my Windows 10 machine using Python 3.

```
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants

# Create list of paths to .doc files
paths = glob('C:\\path\\to\\doc\\files\\**\\*.doc', recursive=True)

def save_as_docx(path):
    # Opening MS Word
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
    doc.Activate ()

    # Rename path with .docx
    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.docx', new_file_abs)

    # Save and Close
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatXMLDocument
    )
    doc.Close(False)

for path in paths:
    save_as_docx(path)
```

Comment: I am getting this error --> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', "Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?\r (C:\\//Users/shreyajain/Documents/Docum...)", 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Shreyansjain Based on the error message, I'm guessing you typed in the file path incorrectly. Although, it's difficult to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: 1) This also allows you to convert PDF files into DOCX, allowing you to read the content of PDF documents.
2) I would suggest to add a TRY at the start of the program, to check that MS-Word is installed :
MSWord_OK = True
try:
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use the `glob` module for tasks like that. Put this in a file `doc2docx.py`. To make it executable, set `chmod +x`. And optionally put that file in your `$PATH` as well, to make it available "everywhere".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import subprocess

for doc in glob.iglob("*.doc"):
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', doc])
```

Though ideally you'd leave the expansion to the shell itself, and call `doc2docx.py` with the files as arguments, like `doc2docx.py *.doc`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write("SYNOPSIS: %s file1 [file2] ...\n"%sys.argv[0])

for doc in sys.argv[1:]:
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', doc])
```

As requested by @pyd, to output to a target directory `myoutputdir` use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.stderr.write("SYNOPSIS: %s file1 [file2] ...\n"%sys.argv[0])

for doc in sys.argv[1:]:
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', '--outdir', 'myoutputdir', doc])
```

Comment: From my tests this only fails when the working/target directory in question is the root of the filesystem, e.g. directly ``C:\`` or ``D:\``. Any other folder works fine. Looks like a bug in ``soffice``. You can specify the output directory by using the option `--outdir <directory-name>`.

Comment: do i need to pass one more argument ?? can you edit your answer

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like to rely on sub-process calls, here is the version with COM client. It is useful if you are targeting windows users without LibreOffice installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 0

for i, doc in enumerate(glob.iglob("*.doc")):
    in_file = os.path.abspath(doc)
    wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    out_file = os.path.abspath("out{}.docx".format(i))
    wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16) # file format for docx
    wb.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Comment: It is clean. However, i wonder is there any platform-independent way to convert doc into docx?

Comment: @longbowking There is no swiss knife library to take care of this when I looked last year. One possible method is to detect OS with `sys.platform` and try Jan Christoph Terasa's approach for Linux, my approach for Windows. Not sure what works for Mac.

Comment: Just tried unoconv with [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/zrrrzzt/docker-unoconv-webservice), doc -> docx, but the resulting docx was damaged (files contained comments that I needed to preserve).

Answer (score 2):

based on dshefman's code,

```
import re
import os
import sys
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants

# Get path from command line argument
ABS_PATH = sys.argv[1]

def save_as_docx(path):
    # Opening MS Word
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
    doc.Activate ()

    # Rename path with .docx
    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.docx', new_file_abs)

    # Save and Close
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatXMLDocument)
    doc.Close(False)

def main():
    source = ABS_PATH

    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for f in filenames:
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)

            if file_extension.lower() == ".doc":
                file_conv = os.path.join(root, f)
                save_as_docx(file_conv)
                print("%s ==> %sx" %(file_conv,f))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join` to specify the correct directory.

```
import os, subprocess

main_dir = os.path.join('/', 'Users', 'username', 'Desktop', 'foldername')

for filename in os.listdir(main_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.doc'):
        print filename
        subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', filename])
```

Answer (score 0):

This version uses doc2docx, which I believe only works on windows or mac. I believe this is the cleanest version so far, if you can use windows. To use it, you must install doc2docx first, which can be done from [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-docx)  (or [pip](https://pypi.org/project/doc2docx/)).

```python
import doc2docx
from glob import glob
import os
def convert_doc_to_docx(folder):
    # Stores all doc files to be removed later
    doc_files = glob('{}/*.doc'.format(folder))
    
    # Now do the conversion. Note that doc2docx converts all files in a given folder
    doc2docx.convert(folder)

    # Remove all old doc_files
    for doc_file in doc_files:
        os.remove(doc_file)

convert_doc_to_docx('C:/Users/user/folder_containing_doc_files/')
```