# Converting doc to docx in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i convert a doc to docx file using python. My code runs but it finds pattern in doc such as 1, 11, 111, 1111 and so on and it strucks. Is there any way to convert a doc to docx file?

Comment: look at this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468442/multiple-doc-to-docx-file-conversion-using-python

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple .doc to .docx file conversion using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468442/multiple-doc-to-docx-file-conversion-using-python)