# Converting doc to docx using python

Tags: python, subprocess, docx

I am trying to convert `.doc` documents to `.docx` documents using `python`. Getting inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468442/multiple-doc-to-docx-file-conversion-using-python), I have tried the following code :

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os

root = "//xxx/"
data_path = root + '/data2/'

os.chdir(data_path)

for doc in glob.iglob("*.doc"):
    
    print(doc)
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', doc], shell = True)
```

But unfortunately litterally nothing happens, i.e. I get no error message, the code is running, the docs are detected (which I check thanks to `print`) but I don't get any result. Any idea how I may troubleshoot this ?

EDITS :

- I am running on Windows, hence `shell = True`
- I have tried double quotes : `'"`
- I have tried without spaces in the names
- When I execute the `subprocess` command on one file alone, I get `1`as output, which I don't knowhow to interpret...

Comment: Running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: On Linux, turn off the shell option. On Windows, put your file name in double quotes: `'"{}"'.format(doc)`

Comment: Do the files have spaces in their names?

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for your answers. I have added the answers in the original post.

Comment: Just open libreoffice once and then run the code. Reply if it works.

Comment: I believe `1` means there's an error (like if the interpreter exit successfully it returns `code=0`, but if exit due to an error it returns `code=1`). Are you sure the file exist, and you have `soffice`? What happens when you `subprocess.call('soffice')`? Odd you say it doesn't give you an error though.

Comment: @Vishnudev @Idlehands thanks for the feedback and sorry for the delay in my reply. This seems to be the issue indeed but I have no idea how to install `soffice` / install and open `libreoffice`. Would you have a link to a good tutorial to learn how to use those ?

Comment: So I installed libreoffice and opened it before running the code but I still get nothing. alternatively I tried running `os.system` but still without success. By the way if I run `os.system("dir")` I get error code 255, which corresponds to "The extended attributes are inconsistent."...