# Is there any package for converting doc file to docx format using python programming in Azure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, azure

I was looking for a server side way of converting the doc file into docx or pdf format using the python programming language without the use of `win32.client`, `comtypes` and API. Iam using it on Azure cloud services. So if there is any other way please help!

Comment: What do you mean for "Azure cloud services" do you have SSH access to it? Or is a Cloud based app like Google Docs? Or is that a VM running Linux/Windows? 
Because there are many approach to it

Comment: Thanks for reply !! It is VM running on Linux

Comment: Last question: is that VM running Windows 10 or Linux?

Comment: VM running Linux.

Comment: If you tell me why you cannot install 'win32com.client' I can give you more more advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few approaches:

- with unoconv: `unoconv -d document --format=docx test.doc`
- with lowriter: `lowriter --convert-to docx test.doc`
- with soffice: `soffice --headless --convert-to docx test.doc`
- with libreoffice: `libreoffice --convert-to docx test.doc`

You can run these command directly from your terminal but if you want you can integrated them into python as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468442/multiple-doc-to-docx-file-conversion-using-python):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import subprocess

for doc in glob.iglob("*.doc"):
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', doc])
```

In the example I'm using `soffice` but you can now substitute `unoconv`, `lowriter` or `libreoffice`.

Answer (score -1):

Need LibreOffice

```py
    import os
    import tempfile
    
    def doc2docx(content):
        """ Convert .doc to .docx with LibreOffice """
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
            filename = os.path.join(tmpdirname, 'filename.doc')
            with open(filename, 'wb') as doc:
                doc.write(content)
                os.system(f'soffice --headless --convert-to docx { filename } --outdir { tmpdirname }')
            filename += 'x'
            with open(filename, 'rb') as docx:
                content = docx.read()
        return content
    
    with open('test.doc', 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
    content = doc2docx(content)
```