# Python - doc to docx file converter input, file path from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi stackoverflow community,

Situation,
I'm trying to run this converter found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468442/multiple-doc-to-docx-file-conversion-using-python),
However what I want is for it to read an array of file path from a text file and convert them.

Reason being, these file path are filtered manually, so I don't have to convert unnecessary files. There are a large amount of unnecessary files in the folder.

How can I go about with this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("file_path",'r') as file_content:
    content=file_content.read()
content=content.split('\n')
```

You can read the data of the file using the method above, Then covert the data of file into a list(*or any other iteratable data type*) so that we can use it with for loop.I used `content=content.split('\n')` to split the data of content by '\n' (*Every time you press enter key, a new line character '\n' is sended*), you can use any other character to split.

```
for i in content:
   # the code you want to execute
```

Note

Some useful links:

- [Split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)
- [File writing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-to-file-in-python/)
- [File read and write](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it helped me towards the right direction, however i'm getting an error, 

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Glad I could help you, and for your TypeError, i have edited my answer, hope this gets it solved.

Comment: that error was because i forgot to add `.read` method by which we take all data in file.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your situation, I guess this is what you want (to only convert certain file in a directory), in which you don't need an extra '.txt' file to process:

```
import os

for f in os.listdir(path):
    if f.startswith("Prelim") and f.endswith(".doc"):
        convert(f)
```

But if for some reason you want to stick with the ".txt" processing, this may help:

```
with open("list.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        convert(line)
```